# select and reference value from dropdown (javascript / HTML)

Tags: javascript, jstl

Struggling a little to determine which item (or none) has been selected from a dropdown (HTML / javascript)

Currently have (which does populate the dropdown correctly)

```
<select name="typeselected" id="typeselected" onchange="typeselected();">
               <option value="">-- Please select --</option>
               <sql:query var="queryresults" dataSource="jdbc/database">
               SELECT id, name from assettype order by name
               </sql:query>
                    <c:forEach var="row" items="${queryresults.rows}">
                    <option value="<c:out value="${row.id}" />"

                        <c:if test="${ row.id == param.id }">
                        selected
                        </c:if>
                        >
                        <c:out value="${row.name}" />

                    </option>
                    </c:forEach>
               </select>
```

The typeselected() function is currently (this also works) -

```
function typeselected()
    {

        if(document.getElementById("typeselected").selectedIndex == 0)
        {
            assetselected = "'%'";
            alert(assetselected);

        }
        else 
        {
            assetselected = document.getElementById("typeselected").value;
            alert(assetselected);
        }

        }
```

I want to use the id that was selected (in the variable 'assetselected') in a separate sql:query.

I have tried

```
where assetypeid = (assetselected)

where assetypeid =  ${assetselected}  

where assetypeid =  '${assetselected}'  

where assetypeid = document.getElementById("typeselected").value
```

But nothing works (the select fails to produce any records)

Any assistance (with the correct sql syntax / command to use) appreciated.

Regards
Ralph

Comment: Thanks Alp. I need val but how do I use val in my next sql select statement =${val} or something else?, I am struggling with sql where syntax

Comment: Sadly your previous reply was deleted (something wrong in stack overflow) so I can no longer see your comments